# Swift - unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value for NSdata in Image

Tags: ios, swift, null

I am bringing the image URL from the webserice. and i am converting it to the Image from the below code.

I am getting error while unwrapping..

### Below is my code

```
   let url = NSURL(string: contactResult.conImageUrl)
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    var imageUrl: UIImage = UIImage()
    println("URL \(url)")
    println("data \(data)")
    imageUrl = UIImage(data: data!)! // here i am getting the error (unexpectedly found nil while      unwrapping an Optional value)
```

here my image URL: http://<...>/peoplefinder/imgs_styles/silhouette.jpg

Can someone please help me out as soon as possible?

Comment: Reason for negative points?

Comment: I get the same error as you do (did)... no idea why

Comment: TommyF...Please see my answer below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can safely unwrap your image as follow:

```
if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
    image  // you can use your image UIImage (note: image it is not an optional here)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Leonardo Savio,  thanks i have implemented But In my Url image is getting downloaded not displaying..so it is coming nil in NSData..For download image what i should do to convert it in UIImage???

Answer (score 2):

It can be avoided by a simple `nil` check.

```
if data != nil
{
    imageUrl = UIImage(data: data!)!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use URL as which you can download it...

### Code Below

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "URL") {

  if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){

      if let imageUrl = UIImage(data: data) {

         //UIImage
     }

 }

}
```

Comment: This is the same answer as Leo Dabus. You should accept his instead of posting this.

Comment: yes, have mentioned new answer because wanted to describe downloading Image URL too. BTW have accepted the answer now..

Comment: Your answer doesn't add anything regarding NSURL either. And after accepting Leo's answer you canceled it and accepted yours again. I mean, obviously, you're free to do as you want, but there's conventions to follow on SO.